# Java socket server killed

Tags: java, serversocket

I've built a Java Socket server which listen to a post on my freebsd server.

The Server class listen to a port, and accept connection.
Every new connection is sent to the ServerManager which save it on a list, and iterate through it to check for new data. the iteration is done through an infinity `while loop`.

I've noticed that after few days running the server has been killed. I don't know what killed it.
Is it possible that the system killed it, like Android does to processes when low on memory and resources?
Is there a way to avoid this? Maybe create some kind of a "Watch Dog" to relaunch it in case of it getting killed?

Comment: maybe your process run out of memory (I don't think it run out of filedescriptors). However this sounds strange to me. The call to `read()` is blocking, so either you use threads, or NIO or the like. Can you share more details on this?

Comment: @Raffaele when the ServerManager find that there is new data available it start a new thread to handle the data and when finished the thread is closed

Comment: @SJuan76 - yes i'm closing them.

Comment: If using threads, I wonder what's in your while loop. Can you share it?

Comment: its a bit long, but in general it iterates throw a HashMap of ClientSocket and Client object (ClientSocket save details about the socket connection include the socket it self) and if the getInputStream().available() > 0 it runs a new thread for handling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the getInputStream().available() > 0 it runs a new thread for handling it

This is not correct. (a) It isn't necessary and (b) what happens if it is zero? Just spawn the thread for the accepted socket, have it deal with the input stream, using blocking reads, and close everything when it finishes (i.e. when read() returns -1 or an exception is thrown).

The accept loop shouldn't do anything with the accepted socket at all, except pass it to the new thread.

Comment: if its zero it continue running to check the next socket connection.
the accept doesn't loop throw anything... it just send the open connection to the manager which then manage the connection. but even if it was wrong written as you said, why would it be killed ?

Comment: @AsafNevo If it's zero you should still create the thread and let the thread take care of the I/O. Otherwise nobody will ever take care of it: you have a socket leak; and you have an explanation for the behaviour you have observed. Just remove that code.

Comment: if its zero doesn't it means that there are 0 bytes to read ? how should i handle it in the thread ?

Comment: @AsafNevo The thread has to read to EOS whether there are zero bytes or sixteen quintillion. It makes no difference to the overall coding. The only difference is that EOS will occur immediately so the 'while' loop will never be entered. Don't make things more complicated than they need to be.